# SQL select multi-ip users

Tags: mysql

I have `user_id` and `ip`

I need to have all IPs that have multiple `user_id`

example table

```
|user_id| |ip|
1, 127.0.0.1
2, 127.0.0.1
3, 82.12.12.12
3, 82.12.12.12
3, 92.15.15.15
```

so my result needs to be `127.0.0.1`

The following Query gives me all IPs that are used multiple times

```
SELECT ip, COUNT(user_id) 
  FROM user_login_histories 
  GROUP BY ip HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT(user_id)) > 1 
  ORDER BY ip
```

what am i missing

Comment: You have no PRIMARY KEY. This may prove problematic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

```
SELECT ip, COUNT(DISTINCT(user_id)) 
FROM user_login_histories 
GROUP BY ip
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT(user_id)) > 1 
ORDER BY COUNT(DISTINCT(user_id))
```

Comment: thats working too. no idea why i couldn't do it myself, actually i was close to do it. thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT ip, GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT user_id)
FROM user_login_histories 
GROUP BY ip 
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT user_id) > 1
ORDER BY COUNT(DISTINCT user_id) DESC
```

Comment: give this men an oscar!